# How to remove session in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

How to remove all session data in codeigniter3?

I don't see any info in manual. I have method `$this->session->unset_userdata()` but in parameter I must write what I want to delete. I need to delete all session data.

I can make foreach on `$this->session->userdata` but I want to know is there any way to remove all data doing a single statement?

Comment: `$this->session->sess_destroy()`

Comment: It is here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=sessions#destroying-a-session and the doc websites link http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 3):

To remove all the session data codeigniter has method named [sess_destroy()](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=sessions#destroying-a-session);

You can call it like below

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

Answer (score 2):

To clear the current session (for example, during a logout), you may simply use either PHP’s session_destroy() function, or the sess_destroy() method. Both will work in exactly the same way:

```
session_destroy();
```

// or

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

More info please refer the CI document

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=sessions#destroying-a-session

Comment: You just copied the CI [docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=sessions#destroying-a-session) article.I suggest you should provide the link as reference

Answer (score 1):

If I want to destroy all session variables:

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

If I want to remove just some variables

```
$this->session->unset_userdata(array(
            'var1' => '',
            'var2' => '',
            'var3' => '',
            'var4' => '',
        ));
```